# a plugin to share a post to social networks via admin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, admin, wp-admin, facebook

I'm not looking for a share this post button for the front end.

I've seen a couple of similar topics here but not exactly what I'm after.

What I would like is a plugin which offers the options in the admin panel to post a link my post to a facebook page, tweets it, perhaps takes the images and sends to flickr and so on. Something which would offer me some controls and configuration to make the oauth connections and then gives me extended sharing features when I make a new post.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I'm a bit overwhelmed when I look through the plugin directory searching for social plugins...

Thanks for any help whatsoever..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [Network Publisher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/network-publisher/)?

Supports 25 networks, probably all you need.

Worth noticing: It uses a third-party service [LinksAlpha](http://help.linksalpha.com/wordpress-plugin-network-publisher).

Comment: I just tried for an hour to get this plugin to work, but it errors when trying to input an API key :(

Comment: Oh, and worth noting, (if it worked) this plugin only offers minimal functionality without upgrading to the paid version.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Sociology for WordPress: Twitter/Facebook Poster](http://codecanyon.net/item/sociology-for-wordpress-twitterfacebook-poster/141390?ref=straightforward) plugin. As said in description:

---

Broadcast your posts to Twitter and Facebook fan pages directly from the WordPress post page.

- Automatically post to Twitter and Facebook fan pages when you publish
  your post.
- Checks for already-published status.
- Select which or both social networks to post to on the post page.
- Bit.ly support with custom credentials.
- Custom Twitter and Facebook credentials.

---

However this plugin is not free. To get it you have to have account there, which you can create at [this page](http://codecanyon.net/signup?ref=straightforward).

Comment: thanks eugene. I was looking for something with a wider range of services than just fb/twitter but this is a good start

Answer (score 0):

[Network Publisher](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/network-publisher/) is great. We've used it for a few client sites and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead there is also a social plugins which I would recommend you to check out is Social Stat Plugin, which allows you to track social activities going on your web page.
You can get this plugin from [Wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-stats-panel/)